# Credit Card Payment IFrame: Unsafe JavaScript attempt to initiate navigation for frame

Tags: php, html, security, iframe

I am trying to integrate a 3rd-party payment provider's "drop-in" payment form into a PHP page. I need just to insert their script tag and form like so:

```
    <script src="https://test.paymentprovider.com/paymentform.js?id=<?php echo $checkoutId; ?>"></script>   
    <form action="http://my.success.url/result.php"></form>
```

On page load, it generates the payment form and loads an additional security validation form inside an iframe which it generates. Upon success, it is meant to redirect to the URL I had provided it (in the `form` tag above). In Firefox, it works perfectly, but in Chrome it doesn't, and instead stays on the initial page. When I used Chrome Inspector to view the console output, I got a bunch of errors, two of which were:

*Unsafe JavaScript attempt to initiate navigation for frame with URL 'http://my.success.url/form.php' from frame with URL 'https://test.paymentprovider.com/v1/redirect.html?redirectUrl=http://my.success.url/result.php&res=36D0D8B607F562A5630AF&target=_top&method=GET'. The frame attempting navigation is targeting its top-level window, but is neither same-origin with its target nor is it processing a user gesture.*

AND

*Uncaught SecurityError: Failed to set the 'href' property on 'Location': The current window does not have permission to navigate the target frame to 'http://my.success.url/result.php&resultpath=%2Fv1%2Fcheckouts%2F36D0D8B607F562A5630AF%2Fpayment'.*

Seeing that is happening only with Chrome, is there any way to "whitelist" test.paymentprovider.com for Chrome?

---

**EDIT**: Apologies, this is actually for a PhoneGap app, which I know runs webkit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This feature is "in development" (https://www.chromestatus.com/features/5851021045661696), are you using a developer build of Chrome? For now you might be able to avoid the problem with the user version but eventually this feature will affect all Chrome versions.

There is a feature request thread asking for a way to disable this feature (https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=5161). There are some solutions within the thread that might work for you, specifically avoiding using the form tag.

Comment: Hey Lachie! Thanks for your answer. Apologies I should've mentioned this earlier, but this is actually for a PhoneGap app, which I know runs webkit